# How to call member of the Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make the function for the array to print 2 dimensional of 3 columns and 3 rows. The thing that I don't know is how to make the program get the input from the user and transfer that to the function on this part:

```
array<array<int, columns>,rows>c[item];
cout<<"2-D Array print: "<<endl;
```

Ive been trying to figure it out and I dont seem to go anywhere :( . Please I need help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const size_t rows=3;
const size_t columns=3;
void printArray(const array<array<int, columns>,rows>&);

int main(){
    const size_t arraysize=9;
    array<int, arraysize>c;

    cout<<"Enter an array of 9 floats: "<<endl;

    for (size_t i=0;i<c.size(); i++) {
        cin>>c[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Normal array print: ";
    for (int item :c) {
        cout<<item<<" ";
    }

    array<array<int, columns>,rows>c[item];
    cout<<"2-D Array print: "<<endl;
}

void printArray(const array<array<int, columns>,rows>&a){
    for(auto const &row:a)
    {
        for(auto const &element:row)
            cout<<element<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? Are you getting a compile error? Unexpected/incorrect behavior? By the way, your code is C++, so I don't know why you keep formatting it using a CSS code snippet, that is not for C++ code.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this, and I don't know how to format it.
Yes when I compile it I get an error in this part
array<array<int, columns>,rows>c[item];
specifically to the last part of it, the c[item];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Since you already have the data at the print point, I interpreted the question as: I don't know how to convert the array in order to pass it to the function)*

Except that [std::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) is a contiguous memory storage and that you might use a uberhack like the following (not guaranteed to work):

```
printArray(reinterpret_cast<const array<array<int, columns>, rows>&>(c));
```

I would feel a lot safer if you used a conversion loop that guarantees data consistency:

```
array<array<int, columns>, rows> printArr;
for (int x = 0; x < rows; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < columns; ++y) {
        printArr[x][y] = c[x*columns + y];
    }
}
printArray(printArr);
```

Output:

```
Enter an array of 9 integers: 

Normal array print: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2-D Array print: 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

<kbd>[**Live Example**](http://ideone.com/wHw9T4)</kbd>

Comment: LOL we've posted two different solution, not sure which one OP wants, it appears that I've to delete mine :D

Comment: That's too early to say! If the post were clear enough we would have just one :/

Comment: I tried both and they work. Thank you very much! If I post in the futuro I will try to make to make my post more clear. I still learning how to use this page. Thank you again.